# Cursor Index Out Of Bounds Error Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Hey I am getting index out of bounds error in my code.

From Activity:

```
            Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.fetchA(b);
            @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
            int a = (int) cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.KEY_I));
            cursor.close();
```

My DB Adaptor:

```
public Cursor fetchA(String b){
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_I}, "b=\""+B+"\"", null, null, null, null);
}
```

Error:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime( 5766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    E/AndroidRuntime( 5766): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index

     -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cursors start out pointing to the position *before* the first row. Consequently, you need to move the cursor to the first row before you can get data. [`Cursor#moveToFirst()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29) or [`#moveToNext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToNext%28%29) ought to do the job.

```
Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.fetchA(b);
cursor.moveToNext();
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
int a = (int) cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.KEY_I));
cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.fetchA(b);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
cursor.moveToNext();
.......
```

Here your retrieval code.