# Cursor Index Out of Bounds exception

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I keep getting this error message:  "Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0" in my code.

I have already referenced the following links, but none of them have worked: 
[Android cursor out of bounds exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37202458/android-cursor-out-of-bounds-exception)

[Cursor index out of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058332/cursor-index-out-of-bounds)

[Cursor Index Out Of Bounds Error Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718446/cursor-index-out-of-bounds-error-android)

[cursor index out of bounds exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738851/cursor-index-out-of-bounds-exception)

```
  public Product getProduct(int id) {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id)},
            null, null, null, null);

    Product product = new Product();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor != null) {
        product.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
        product.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        product.setSize(cursor.getDouble(2));
        product.setHp(cursor.getDouble(3));
        product.setCategory(cursor.getString(4));
        product.setPowerType(cursor.getString(5));
        product.setExplosionProof(cursor.getInt(6));
        product.setRPM(cursor.getInt(7));
        product.setBypassPSI(cursor.getInt(8));
        product.setGPM(cursor.getInt(9));
        product.setPrice(cursor.getDouble(10));
        cursor.close();
    }

    db.close();
    return product;
}
```

And here are my constants:

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Products";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "'_id'";
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Now, it won't go into the if-loop. I got that query model straight from another stack overflow question.

Comment: It will happen if your result is empty. Can you please Show the complete stacktrace

Comment: What's the point of having `if (cursor != null)` right after a line that calls `cursor.moveToFirst()` ?

Comment: add check if(cursor.moveToFirst()) rather than if (cursor != null)

Comment: when I do if(cursor.moveToFirst()), it never enters the if-loop

Comment: you should used `if(cursor.moveToNext())`

Comment: I did that, but it still doesn't enter the if-loop

Comment: then it not getting any data debug and check it

Comment: Debug id for null that you passing.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong. In my database there is an id value of 2, which is the int that I am passing in. Do you see anything wrong with the query?

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the cursor is empty, as such you need to ascertain why. It could be that there is no underlying data or it could be that the cursor where clause is excluding all data. From what you have provided it is impossible to determine why.

I would suggest removing the where clause to see if this changes matters.

i.e. instead of

```
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
        TABLE_NAME,
        null,
        COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
        new String[] { Integer.toString(id)},
        null, null, null, null);
```

use :-

```
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
        TABLE_NAME,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null, null, null, null);
```

This would return all rows from the cursor, if this works then the issue is with the where clause (3rd and 4th parameters passed to `db.query`). If it doesn't resolve the issue then it is likely that the table itself has no rows.

You could circumvent the CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException by using :-

```
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        product.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
        product.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        product.setSize(cursor.getDouble(2));
        product.setHp(cursor.getDouble(3));
        product.setCategory(cursor.getString(4));
        product.setPowerType(cursor.getString(5));
        product.setExplosionProof(cursor.getInt(6));
        product.setRPM(cursor.getInt(7));
        product.setBypassPSI(cursor.getInt(8));
        product.setGPM(cursor.getInt(9));
        product.setPrice(cursor.getDouble(10));
    } else {
        // setup to return a product not found
    }
    cursor.close();
```

However, this won't fix the underlying issue that the cursor is not returning any rows.

You could use something like the following to get more information regarding the cursor (running with the cursor selecting all rows as per change above). This should work for any cursor :-

```
    int rowcount = cursor.getCount();
    String colnames = "";
    for (String columns : cursor.getColumnNames()) {
        colnames = colnames +
                "Column Index=" +
                Integer.toString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columns)) +
                " Name=>" +
                columns +
                "<  ";
    }
    Log.d("DBCHK","Table has " + Integer.toString(rowcount) + " rows. With columns:- " + colnames);
    String values;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        values = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            values = values +
                    "Column = " +
                    cursor.getColumnName(i) +
                    " Index=" +
                    Integer.toString(i) +
                    " Value=" + cursor.getString(i) + ": ";
        }
        Log.d("DBCHK",values);
    }
```

This would write data to the log along the lines of :-

```
D/DBCHK: Table has 2 rows. With columns:- Column Index=0 Name=>_id<  Column Index=1 Name=>myfloat<  
D/DBCHK: Column = _id Index=0 Value=null: Column = myfloat Index=1 Value=56.7897: 
D/DBCHK: Column = _id Index=0 Value=null: Column = myfloat Index=1 Value=87.7655:
```

There will be a line per row, these preceded with a line listing the number of rows and what the columns are.